# How can I solve this probability problem?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, bayes-theorem

A most unusual Irish pub serves only Guinness and Harp. The owner of this pub observes that 85% of his male costumers drink Guinness as opposed to 35% of his female costumers. On any given evening, this pub owner notes that there are three times as many males as females. What is the probability that the person sitting beside the fireplace drinking Guinness is female?

So what I did was
Males that drink Guinness are 0.85

Females that drink Guinness are 0.35

There are also 0.75 males and 0.25 females

So I took everyone that wasn't female and drinks Guinness by doing this:

0.75 + (0.25 * (1-0.35) = 0.9125

So I subtract this to 1

1 - 0.9125 = 0.0875

And so I think the answer is 0.0875 or 8.75%.

Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: From what I see, You have found the percentage of females who drink guinness. But do you think that's the probability? Say 100% females drink guinness, and 0.1% of men drink guinness. You would say the probability is 25%, but you can intuitively see that it should be much more than that. Think about why it feels wrong, and what you are intuitively comparing.

Comment: But what I thought I did was find the probability of a girl drinking guinness when there are 3 times as many males as females. So of the 25% of females that there are, I took the 35% that drink guinness and said that the result is the probability of the one in the fireplace is a female drinking Guinness. Am I missing something, or like not making sense with what i did, is that if not, I dont know what else I can do

Comment: You are right, That is the probability of a female drinking guinness, However, It is given that the person is drinking guinness, so the probability changes. One simple flaw in your reasoning is that the probability of it being a woman is 8.75% and the probabilty of it being man is 63.75%, which does not add up to 1.

Comment: Hmm so what you think I should do instead? And should it add up to 1 I mean there are also the people that is drinking Harp, isnt the rest to add to 1 there?

Comment: You can start by thinking about your sample space. What percentage of the total people is your sample space?

Comment: Oh I get it now, I already know that the person is drinking Guinness so what I must take into account is that if its female or male, not that if its female and that its also drinking Guinness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with your attempt has been elaborated in the comments : you calculated only the probability that the person is Female and drinking Guinness. You have not taken into account the fact that it was known that the person was drinking Guinness. This will increase the probability significantly.

See, the person you see is drinking Guinness. Therefore, the desired probability is the probability that the person is female *GIVEN* that he/she is drinking Guinness.

Thus, if $F$ denotes the event "the person is female" and $G$ denotes the event "the person is drinking Guinness", then we need $P(F | G) = \frac{P(F \cap G)}{P(G)}$.

To calculate $P(F \cap G)$, we need to interpret what we have. It is known that $85$% of the male customers drink Guinness, so $P(G|M) = 0.85$. Similarly, $P(G | F) = 0.35$. Additionally, $P(M) = 0.75$ and $P(F) = 0.25$.

From here, $P(F \cap G) = P(G | F)P(F) = 0.0875$ (as per your calculation).

On the other hand, $P(G)$ is what we don't know. We do it using the Bayes' rule : condition on whether the person is a man or woman, and multiply by the respective probability of the person being man or woman. That is :
$$
P(G) = P(G | F)P(F) + P(G |M)P(M) = 0.0875 + 0.85 \times 0.75 = 0.725
$$

Therefore, the actual answer is $\frac{0.0875}{0.725} = \frac{7}{58}$.

Comment: Oh thank you! I get it now, I wasnt taking into account the fact that I already knew the person was drinking Guinness, so it was just a matter of knowing if it was female or male

Comment: Exactly, good you understood. Thank you for the acceptance!

Comment: What does 0.35 stay for in the end of your answer?

Comment: @user Thank you, I have corrected it. $P(G | M)$ is $0.85$ and $P(M)$ is $0.75$.